# 7z not working from shell script under putty

Tags: linux, shell, putty, 7zip

I want to backup a file periodically using the **7z** command.

Below is *testscript.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
SRCDIR="/var/www/html/folder2beBackedup/"
DESTDIR="/var/www/html/backups/"
FILENAME=bk_test-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).7z
7za a $DESTDIR$FILENAME $SRCDIR
```

I run the script in **putty** like so:

```
/bin/bash /var/www/html/testscript.sh
```

But **putty** returns this error: "Cannot find 1 file".  See [image]

If I directly run the **7z** command via **putty** then it works, but the same command is not working from *testcript.sh*.

Comment: Check the environment variable `PATH` - or use the absolute path for 7z

Comment: i have tried by giving the hardcoded file name & path (supposed that the date function is not working), but that also not worked.

Comment: Are you running the script from cron as a different user? Maybe it doesn't have read permission to the source files.

Comment: Or... maybe your dir name has a space in it, and you're not quoting the argument?

Comment: Run `/bin/bash -x /var/www/html/testscript.sh` and report its output here.

Comment: @john1024, same output with this.

Comment: @Knight `bash -x script`  shows diagnostic output.  It will not look the same as a script run without `-x`.  Try it on any of your working scripts to see.

Comment: @john1024, sorry my bad, i mis-understood it.  Below is the output with -x  
    `+ SRCDIR=$'/var/www/html/folder2beBackedup/\r'`  


    `+ DESTDIR=$'/var/www/html/backups/\r'`  

    `++ date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`  

    `+ FILENAME=$'bk_test-20160616222153.7z\r'`  

    `+ 7za a /var/www/html/backups/\rbk_test-20160616222153.7z\r `  

    `$'/var/www/html/folder2beBackedup/\r'`  

I got it, \r is causing the issue, EOL,    
So how to resolve it?

Comment: @Knight Very good.  Note the `\r` in the output. That shows that your script file has DOS/Windows-style line-endings.  Just remove them, e.g., with `tr -d '\r' <oldscript >newscript`.

Comment: @john1024, It worked thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect there is a copy/paste error with your `SRCDIR` variable, as the `WARNING: No more files` output indicates that it is trying to scan a directory with no name.  Simply specifying the wrong variable name (and thus no directory) would cause it to include the files from the current directory, so it's probably something more sinister like an invalid character in your script somewhere.  Have you tried looking at the script with `hexdump -C` to ensure there's no weird stray characters anywhere?

If I use a source directory named `"/tmp/src/"^M`, where `^M` is literally the carriage return character (inserted in vim with `^V ^M`), I get the same result as shown in your screenshot.

Here's an excerpt from [the bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info):

1. **Check whether your script or data has DOS style end-of-line characters**

   - Use `cat -v yourfile` or `echo "$yourvariable" | cat -v` .

     DOS carriage returns will show up as `^M` after each line.

     If you find them, delete them using `dos2unix` (a.k.a. `fromdos`) or `tr -d '\r'`